# Consulta sql repite filas

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy entrampado con una query en mysql que debo realizar y no me esta funcionando, resulta que me esta repitiendo las filas como se ve en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La query que estoy trabajando la tengo asi:

```
select 
asig.fecha_asignacion, asig.num_guia_despacho, asig.tecnico_id, asig.user_id,
det.id, det.cantidad, det.material_id, det.asignacion_material_id,
tec.nombre_primario, tec.nombre_secundario, tec.ape_pat, tec.ape_mat,
serv.servicio
from asignacion_materials as asig
inner join det_asignacion_materials as det on asig.id = det.asignacion_material_id
inner join tecnicos as tec on asig.tecnico_id = tec.id
inner join tecnico_servicios as ts on tec.id = ts.tecnico_id
inner join servicios as serv on serv.id = ts.servicio_id
where ts.id = 1
```

Alguien me podria orientar un poquito en que me estoy saltando, la verdad que estoy mareado...

Saludos a todos

Comment: prueba usando `SELECT DISTINCT` aunque debería revisar los `join` para que se repita, como que usas un `join` de más o algo, no debería pasar.

Comment: No veo ningún registro duplicado en el resultado. Considero que te falta explicar qué registros consideras duplicados y por qué. Toma en cuenta que es preferible incluir los datos como texto y no como imagen en la pregunta.

Comment: Si una asignación tiene dos materiales ¿qué es mas importante: al asignación o los materiales? ¿cuál sería el resultado: un renglón por asignación o un renglón por material?

Answer (score 0):

Evidentemente te falta una relación en un INNER JOIN. Podrías comenzar tu query con la tablas tecnicos_servicios e ir sumando de a un INNER y ver en que momento se empiezan a duplicar los registros

Comment: Tienes la suficiente reputación para poder comentar, si proporcionas una respuesta trata de poner un ejemplo y explicarlo de la mejor forma posible